# How can I add adsense to my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adsense

I already programmed small chrome extension that when you click on it's icon it sends you to a specific URL.

Now I need to add an Adsense Advertisement included in my extension code, so that the ads appear at youtube.com at the right ,

Please look at the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhVz5.jpg, I just marked where I want my ads to appear.

I've already seen an extension that does that, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Did you read Adsense terms and conditions?

Comment: Any update on this? The AdSense terms still state that ads cannot be shown in or by Chrome Extensions. Are there any possible alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the program policies:
Ads in Chrome Apps and Extensions
https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/program_policies

**Currently, AdSense may not be used to serve ads in Chrome extensions or packaged apps, per AdSense policies.**

Comment: Here it says its allowed? http://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-app-05

Comment: Yes, but that's for website. There the web page are saved on the host (and not on your computer).

Comment: - packaged apps -> is not allowed to place Google adsense here. Because it run offline on your computer.
- Normal app (like youtube.com) can show Google Adsense.

Answer (score 0):

AdSense in packaged apps is being worked on. See the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/chromium-apps/_47r_YKRdjA

In the meantime, star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132602

Comment: Has there been any news since 2013?