# How do i put ads on my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adsense

I saw that adsense changed its rules recently and now ads can be put on chrome extensions. I dont know how to sign up though since i require a website to sign up normally. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Gentle reminder that by [Single Purpose Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose#fourteen) you can only show ads if that's the _main purpose_ of your extension, not in addition to other unrelated functionality.

Comment: @Xan Doesnt that only apply to injecting ads, not to ads on the options page, etc?

Comment: @DanielHerr The policy is quite open to interpretation; I'm just reminding it exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293998/how-can-i-add-adsense-to-my-chrome-extension

Comment: That one is out dated. Chromes policies have changed since then. Apparently adsense hasnt.