# Displaying Adsense Ads in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, adsense, adsense-api, adsense-anchor-ads

I'm Trying to Monetize a Google Chrome Extension, The Extension has a large panel that display content to the users.

I want to add Small Sized Advertisement from Google Adsense into the extension panel. However as far as I know for an Adsense account to be approved, it has to be associated with an existing website that has some good content inside.

What are my options to user Adsense? are there other Ads Providers that can be helpful?

Comment: For the first question, you [can't use AdSense in an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14666184).

Comment: Also quite interested in this question. Did you find any alternatives to adsense in extensions?

Comment: There are several alternatives, Rakuten Marketing; which I tried to use but their process was too heavy. Finally we changed the procedure and forced users to go to a website where they can view the content and ads alongside with it. Note that Chrome will keep trying to prevent you from showing ads inside of it in different ways.