# What type of ads are allowed in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, adsense, ads

The question of Adsense in extensions has been asked in various ways over the years and there are conflicting messages out there. I'm asking here now to get the most recent info from someone in the know.

[This article](https://sproutsocial.com/insights/google-chrome-extensions-ads/) seems to say Adsense is allowed, but it's several years old. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088491/displaying-adsense-ads-in-chrome-extension) seems to say no.

The screenshot below from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies) seems to indicate no as well.

If I can't use Adsense, does that mean all ads are off limits? If ads are allowed, but Adsense is not, what alternatives are there?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you want to show ads inside own extension pages, I see only answers that like [this one](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-put-ads-to-you-chrome-extension) saying there are no ad networks that work with extensions. If you find one, I guess you can use it.

Comment: Of note: [Single Purpose Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose#thirteen) implies that you can use ads in your extension only if _adding ads is your extensions's only purpose._

Answer (score 2):

The single purpose policy is confusing for me too. as @Xan commencted the single purpose treats ads as a purpose of an extension which doesn't make sense to me. Why would anybody install an extension that only serves ads? I think the policy should be clearer about where CWS stands from ads.